# What reasons are behind the firing of many pageview events on a Data Layer?

Tags: google-analytics, pageviews, data-layers

We are starting to do a migration from a UA property to a GA4, the team shared with us the prod page; we have an issue of many pageviews firing when we reload the page (min of 5 pageviews to 10 pageviews). Client told us there is no Data Layer installed, but AdSwerve is telling us otherwise.

- Client already asked their dev, they have nothing installed.
- I looked if there were any GTM containers installed that could be generating the problem, there is none.

Comment: You don't need Adswerve to debug DL. It's all in the Console and Network. Migrating UA to GA4 requires certain technical expertise. It might be easier for you to just funnel UA property into GA4 property and call it migration.